# How to change the play icon when audio is completed in react native track player

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-track-player. My problem is that when my audio completes then my resume icon doesn't automatically change into play-icon. Please, somebody, look at my code and help me.

Hi, I am using react-native-track-player. My problem is that when my audio completes then my resume icon doesn't automatically change into play-icon. Please, somebody, look at my code and help me.

```js
<Button
  onPress={() => this.playOrpause()}
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#1191cf',
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
    bottom: 5,
  }}>
  {this.state.AudioStatus || !this.playing ? (
    <Icon
      name="ios-play"
      style={{ color: '#1191cf', fontSize: 32, left: 6 }}
    />
  ) : (
      <Icon
        name="md-pause"
        style={{ color: '#1191cf', fontSize: 24, left: 6 }}
      />
    )}
</Button>




playOrpause = async () => {
  //this.setState({AudioStatus: !this.state.AudioStatus});
  const currentTrack = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();
  if (currentTrack == null || !this.playing) {
    TrackPlayer.reset();
    this.setPlayer(
      this.props.audio,
      this.props.title,
      this.props.speaker,
      this.props.speaker_image,
    );
    TrackPlayer.play();
  } else {
    console.log(await TrackPlayer.getState());
    if ((await TrackPlayer.getState()) === 2 || (await TrackPlayer.getState()) === 0 || (await TrackPlayer.getState()) === 1 || (await TrackPlayer.getState()) === 'paused' || (await TrackPlayer.getState()) === 'ready' || (await TrackPlayer.getState()) === 'idle') {
      TrackPlayer.play();
    } else {
      TrackPlayer.pause();
    }
  }
  this.UpdateTrackUI();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Havn't used `react-native-track-player` before but by observing your code your icon is based on `this.state.AudioStatus || !this.playing`

Since `this.playing` is not a `state/prop`, changing the value of `this.playing` will not cause a re-render and thus your button will not change. If you have nothing wrong in other parts migrating the `this.playing` to `this.state.playing` should work :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener. react-native-track-player has a set of events, please check the docs for more info at https://react-native-track-player.js.org/

```
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

TrackPlayer.addEventListener('PlaybackQueueEnded', (event) => {

// your code to change image/icon
})
```

PlaybackQueueEnded event is fired when trackplayer has successfully played the audio/audios.